# How do i output all the rows under a certain column in delphi?

Tags: database, delphi

```
procedure TfrmPlayers.btnPlayersClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  memoPlayers.Clear;
  with dbgPlayers do
    begin
      for i := 0 to FieldCount-1 do
      begin
        memoPlayers.Lines.Add(Fields[i].AsString);
      end;
    end;
end;
```

I found this solution for outputting all the columns in the first row.
But i want to have it output all the rows under a certain column.

Comment: So loop through the rows, and output only the field you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through all rows (as @BugFinder mentioned in the comments). You may consider to include two additional steps:

- Remember the record in the dataset for later navigation using `TBookMark`.
- Disable the data display while inserting the data using `DisableControls`.

Example (based on your code):

```
procedure TfrmPlayers.btnPlayersClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   i: integer;
   b: TBookMark;
begin
   // Clear existing data
   memoPlayers.Clear;

   // Get the data
   b := dbgPlayers.GetBookmark;
   dbgPlayers.DisableControls;
   try
      dbgPlayers.First;
      while not dbgPlayers.Eof do begin
         for i := 0 to dbgPlayers.FieldCount-1 do begin
            memoPlayers.Lines.Add(dbgPlayers.Fields[i].AsString);
         end{for};
         dbgPlayers.Next;
      end{while};
   finally
      if dbgPlayers.BookmarkValid then dbgPlayers.GotoBookmark(b);
      dbgPlayers.FreeBookmark(b);
      dbgPlayers.EnableControls;
   end{try};
end;
```

Comment: A minor slip maybe:  You have removed the  "with" (hooray), but I'm not sure about `memoPlayers.Lines.Add(Fields[i].AsString)` or the `for` loop..  Surely, it needs `dbgPlayers.` in front of `Fields` and, anyway, it seems unlikely that all the player names are stored in different columns of the same row?  More likely there is one player name per row and the code needs to add that field value for each dataset row?

Comment: @MartynA, thanks, I should be more precise. And you are probably right about the player names.Maybe a comment from the OP will make this more clear. Thanks again for this comment.